# Calculate and display the amount of webpage loaded as a loading animation before the page content is displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, loading, dom-manipulation

So, I am just creating a new eLearning website but the issue is that it has a bit slow loading speed so I would like to display a loading animation similar to [this](https://jsbin.com/huyusu/3/edit?html,css,js,output) but it works only for images. Is it possible to calculate and display how much percentage of the whole document is loaded as a loading animation using normal Javascript or with any of its libraries/frameworks?

I believe it should be similar to this:

```
<head>
    <script src="path/to/loading.js"></script>
</head>
```

The webpage has many nested div elements like any normal website. So, is it possible to convert the code given in the link to somehow check the number of div tags that are loaded instead of the number of img tags that are loaded?

Or maybe make something like if the page is opened, loading animation reaches a random integer between 30% and 60%, and for the first second and then for every 0.5 seconds or so, it increases by a random amount (say 3% to 10%), and then if the page is still not loaded the animation is paused at 99% and remains there till page gets loaded? After it loads, it can disappear and the content can be displayed. However, if the page gets loaded while animation is going on, animation should reach 100% immediately and end and the page content should be displayed.

Comment: Rendering the DOM is generally instant, having a loading indicator for this would then be pointless.  Ideally you need to find what's slow maybe you have lots of libs, maybe a lot of them the loading could be deferred, lots of large images may have an effect too.  I would suggest looking at the network tab in developer mode and see what's taking the time.

Comment: @Keith I know but I am doing this for a college project and they want more pages and features so I thought loading would be a really good idea. I will minify the files to make it fast later. But I need the loading animation for phase 1 evaluation. Cant minify files here and the page that has a lot of videos takes quite a while (around 2 seconds) to load. And if I'm doing this for one page, then why not just put it in all other pages too

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented any loading animation which shows percentage but I'm not sure doing such thing is a good idea or not. Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZnLZFRylbs

You can implement a default loader(so called spinner in bootstrap) for whole page and remove the loader when document is ready with

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   //REMOVE THE LOADER HERE
});
```

or jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //REMOVE THE LOADER HERE
});
```

Check `document.readyState` for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is "window.onload"
It will wait all is loaded(image script style) trigger

Or you can send header and footer on first,then ajax content
but if you want "show progress" is imprecise,i think it just hint user now is load

```
$(()=>{
   //Create loader
})
$(window).on("load",()=>{
    //Remove loader
})
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything close to what the OP is asking for, it just allows running JS when the loading is complete. You could maybe use this to remove a loading spinner of some sort that doesn't depend on the percentage currently loaded, but that's covered by the other answer already.

Comment: But His detailed requirement is that his page has a large number of videos. I think he should want to wait until the videos is loaded. PS When DOM is not loaded, the page won’t have anything